# Prove that if $ \gcd(a,m) = 1 $ and $ a b \equiv a c ~ (\operatorname{mod} ~ m) $, then $ b \equiv c ~ (\operatorname{mod} ~ m) $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, gcd-and-lcm

> **Problem.** Prove that if $ \gcd(a,m) = 1 $ and $ a b \equiv a c  \pmod m $, then $ b \equiv c \pmod m $.

I have $ m | a b - a c $, or $ m | a (b - c) $, and I know that if $ \gcd(a,m) = 1 $, then $ n | b - c $. I just don’t know what lemma I can use here.

Comment: You have that m|(b-c) by Euclid's lemma, so $b\equiv c \pmod m$

Comment: Um,  if you have m|b-c, you are done.  What more do you possibly need to show?

Comment: Either m|a or m| b-c. Since gcd(m,a) =1. m cannot divide a. So m| b-c